# Permanent permissions change to /dev/vhost-net

Tags: permissions

I'm interested in making sure that `/dev/vhost-net` is read/writable by group `vhost-net`. I do this using chown + chmod. However, after every reboot (and in fact after every reset of the device), it resets back to root/root. I tried adding a udev rule:

```
> cat /etc/udev/rules.d/40-permissions.rules

KERNEL=="vhost-net", GROUP="vhost-net", MODE="0660"
```

This doesn't appear to have any effect. How can I make this permission change permanent?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and I think I figured it out. It seems to me the `/dev/vhost-net` file may be present, even if the `vhost-net` kernel module is not loaded.

When I create the udev rule (same as yours) and (re)load the module by executing `rmmod vhost-net && modprobe vhost-net` the configuration is picked up just fine.

To make it persistent I added `vhost-net` to the `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`.

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.4. This solved the problem, thanks.